# Added checkboxes, can't find up('checkboxgroup')

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I have a checkboxgroup as defined below. (The checkboxgroup has a 'change' event defined in a controller which I hope doesn't matter here.)

The handlers show the following problem:

- When trying to access checkbox.up('checkboxgroup') for startItems checkboxes, they get the checkboxgroup.
- When trying to access checkbox.up('checkboxgroup') for added checkboxes, they get `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong, or how could I possibly get the references correct?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.CheckItems', {
extend : 'Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',
defaults : {
    margin : "0 10 0 0"
},
...
handleUncheckOne:function(checkbox,checked) {
    console.log(checkbox.up('checkboxgroup'));
    // Output depends on whether it is a startItems checkbox one or a new one...
},
initComponent : function() {
    var list = [{
                xtype:'checkbox',
                boxLabel: "All", 
                name: "#ALL#", 
                inputValue: "#ALL#",
                checked :  false,
                handler: me.handleCheckAll
            }];
    Ext.each(startItems, function(entry, i) {
        list.push( {
            boxLabel : entry.label,
            name : entry.name,
            inputValue : entry.value,
            checked : true,
            handler : me.handleUncheckOne
        });
    });

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items : list
    });
    me.callParent(arguments);
},
addToList:function(names) {
    var me = this;
    var list = [];
    Ext.each(names,function(entry) {
        list.push(Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Checkbox',Ext.applyIf(Ext.clone(me.defaults),{
            boxLabel : entry.label,
            name : entry.name,
            inputValue : entry.value,
            checked : true,
            handler : me.handleUncheckOne,
            listeners : {
                change: function() {
                    me.fireEvent("change") // Fire change event on checkboxgroup
                }
            }
        })));
    });
    if(list.length>0) {
        me.items.addAll(list);
        me.doLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly modify the items collection like that. Doing so, you circumvent some code that would set the `ownerCt` property of the new checkbox, which explain why the `up` query is not working.

Your code should rather looks like this:

```
addToList: function(names) {
    var me = this; // hope this it the checkbox group
    var list = [];
    Ext.each(names, function(entry) {
        // adding with the container's add method
        me.add(new Ext.form.field.Checkbox(Ext.applyIf({
            boxLabel : entry.label,
            name : entry.name,
            inputValue : entry.value,
            checked : true,
            handler : me.handleUncheckOne,
            listeners : {
                change: function() {
                    me.fireEvent("change") // Fire change event on checkboxgroup
                }
            }
        }, me.defaults)));
    });
}
```